# Set value and text of select option from javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I sett the value and text of a select option from javascript?

```
function getYear() 
{
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    return year;
}


<select name="dateformat" onchange="change_date();" id="dateformat">
   <option value="??" >??</option>
</select>
```

I want the value of getYear() in place of ??.

Answer (score 6):

```
var option = document.getElementById("dateformat").options[0];
option.value = option.text = getYear();
```

**Edit**: I thought OP meant to find a way to *add* an option to a `<select>`. But it seems it's more like editing an existing one. So there.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```
var year = getYear();
var combo = document.getElementById('dateformat');
combo.options[combo.options.length] = new Option(year ,year );
```